# Google Spreadsheet Sort Specific Rows (dynamically)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

In my spreadsheet I get data from several APIs (which is being updated automatically and frequently)

These are my 2 questions:

a) My API gets data like this:

- A
- B
- A
- B
- A
- B

I want to copy the data into other columns, so I did on different columns

- =E1
- =E2
- =E3
- =E4

To not manually type it I can select it and drag it down.

But what if my data is:

- A
- B
- C
- D
- A
- B
- C
- D
- A
- B
- C

I can't select and drag down the Formula in a 3rd / 4th step for example.

I don't want to manually do it, because its too much.

Here I would need to type:

- =E1
- =E4
- =E7

b)
Let's say my data is:

```
Author | Price | Title | Publishing Year 
Author | Price | Title | Publishing Year 
Author | Price | Title | Publishing Year
```

How can I (dynamically, because this data set is being updated) create a new set of columns for this to filer it by AUTHOR for example.

- Column A,B,C,D should be AUTHOR 1 and rest
- Column E,F,G,H should be AUTHOR 2 and rest

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Please share your spreadsheet with a public link so the community can take a look at it and also provide the output you are getting from your current solution.